Kotlink KMP: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 caused by a cocoapod dependency
We have a Kotlin KMP library which we are compiling for Android, iOS and JS platforms. Recently we have added an AI feature to it and are using the TensorFlow Lite on all 3 platforms. For iOS we have added the TensorFlow Lite as a cocoapod dependency, like this:
    cocoapods {
        summary = "..."
        homepage = "..."

        framework {
            baseName = "...."

            export(project(":module_a"))
            export(project(":module_b"))

            freeCompilerArgs += "-Xallocator=std"
            freeCompilerArgs += "-linker-options"
            freeCompilerArgs += "-application_extension"

            isStatic = false


            binaryOption("bundleShortVersionString", rootProject.extra["versionName"] as String)
            binaryOption("bundleVersion", (rootProject.extra["versionCode"] as Int).toString())
        }

        ios.deploymentTarget = "14"

        pod(
            name = "TensorFlowLiteObjC",
            version = "2.5.0",
            moduleName = "TFLTensorFlowLite"
        )
    }

Everything looks good until we try to compile the lib with ./gradlew podPublishXCFramework which results with the following error:
> Task :linkPodDebugFrameworkIosArm64 FAILED
w: Interop library /.../module_b-cinterop-TFLTensorFlowLite can't be exported with -Xexport-library
e: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld invocation reported errors
Please try to disable compiler caches and rerun the build. To disable compiler caches, add the following line to the gradle.properties file in the project's root directory:
    
    kotlin.native.cacheKind.iosArm64=none
    
Also, consider filing an issue with full Gradle log here: https://kotl.in/issue
The /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld command returned non-zero exit code: 1.
output:
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-ldl'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_TfLiteInterpreterAllocateTensors", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter allocateTensorsWithError:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteInterpreterCreate", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter initWithModelPath:options:delegates:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteInterpreterDelete", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter dealloc] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteInterpreterGetInputTensor", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter cTensorOfType:atIndex:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteInterpreterGetInputTensorCount", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter initWithModelPath:options:delegates:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter cTensorOfType:atIndex:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensorCount", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter initWithModelPath:options:delegates:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteInterpreterInvoke", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter invokeWithError:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteInterpreterOptionsAddDelegate", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter initWithModelPath:options:delegates:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
      -[TFLInterpreter initWithModelPath:options:delegates:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteInterpreterOptionsCreate", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter initWithModelPath:options:delegates:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteInterpreterOptionsDelete", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter initWithModelPath:options:delegates:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteInterpreterOptionsSetErrorReporter", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter initWithModelPath:options:delegates:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteInterpreterOptionsSetNumThreads", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter initWithModelPath:options:delegates:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteInterpreterResizeInputTensor", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter resizeInputTensorAtIndex:toShape:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteModelCreateFromFile", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter initWithModelPath:options:delegates:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteModelDelete", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter initWithModelPath:options:delegates:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteTensorByteSize", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter copyData:toInputTensorAtIndex:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
      -[TFLInterpreter dataFromTensor:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteTensorCopyFromBuffer", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter copyData:toInputTensorAtIndex:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteTensorData", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter dataFromTensor:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteTensorDim", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter shapeOfTensor:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteTensorName", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter tensorOfType:atIndex:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteTensorNumDims", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter shapeOfTensor:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteTensorQuantizationParams", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter tensorOfType:atIndex:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteTensorType", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter tensorOfType:atIndex:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteVersion", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__sub_I_TFLInterpreter.mm in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
      __GLOBAL__sub_I_TFLInterpreter.mm in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteXNNPackDelegateCreate", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter initWithModelPath:options:delegates:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteXNNPackDelegateDelete", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter dealloc] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
  "_TfLiteXNNPackDelegateOptionsDefault", referenced from:
      -[TFLInterpreter initWithModelPath:options:delegates:error:] in TFLTensorFlowLite[6](TFLInterpreter.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

We have tried adding freeCompilerArgs += listOf("-linker-option", "-framework", "-linker-option", "TensorFlowLiteObjC") and linkerOpts("-framework", "TensorFlowLiteObjC") to the cocoapods.framework{} section in the build.gradle.kts file, but to no avail.
We are using Kotlin v1.9.24. Updating to v2.0.0 has no effect.
We are getting a similar error if we try adding any other 3rd party dependency via Cocapads.

I've had success bringing in a dependency as a XCFramework using these instructions from the Kotlin docs.
And I see from this SO answer that TensorFlow Lite is available as a XCFramework. Perhaps you could try that way if Cocoapod is not working for you.

Thanks @PeterTran. I'll have a look at the first suggestion. The second one doesn't work for me.

Try to add -fmodules compiler option:
    pod(
        name = "TensorFlowLiteObjC",
        version = "2.5.0",
        moduleName = "TFLTensorFlowLite"
        extraOpts = listOf("-compiler-option", "-fmodules")
    )

Read more:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-cocoapods-libraries.html#support-for-objective-c-headers-with-import-directives
